# JavaScript Function Declaration vs Object Literal

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript object creation using literals vs custom constructor functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995100/javascript-object-creation-using-literals-vs-custom-constructor-functions)
>   [Function vs. Object Literal Notaion - Which is better, or is it a matter of preference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079544/function-vs-object-literal-notaion-which-is-better-or-is-it-a-matter-of-pref)

Could anyone enlighten me what is the difference between below two ways of creating objects in JavaScript or more specifically drawbacks/advantages of them:

```
Function Foo() {
   function bar () {...}
}
```

And

```
var Foo = {
   bar : function() {}
}
```

Also since in latter way, there is no `this` keyword, how can I make it object **instance** member ?

Comment: Post some valid code - that first code sample is no good - and they do completely different things. I'm not sure how you want to compare them, since the first defines a function that can be used as constructor (with `new`) while the second is an object literal with a function. Anyways, you'll have `this` in the second bar function as well, not sure why you say that there isn't.

Comment: @Bergi, you're probably right about the dupes, but most answers there aren't very good or helpful IMHO. I'd say the second one has the best answers.

Comment: *how can I make it object instance member* What does this mean? `Foo` is already an object, an instance so to speak.